# How can I prevent URL rewriting with JSESSIONID in WebLogic?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, weblogic

JSF, PrimeFaces 6.0, WebLogic.

I have a menuitem like this:

```
<p:menuitem id="rm_id" title="rm_title" value="rm_value" url="#{MyBean.myExternalUrl}"/>
```

This URL redirect works sometimes but usually not works. When I look for differences between work and not work URL, I see JSF adds "JSESSIONID" to URL and this causes "page not found".

I have tried to add "faces-redirect=true" my external URL and I have tried to add conf to web.xml like below, but they are not working. Still sometimes JSF adds JSESSIONID to external URL.

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I add configuration to WEB-INF/weblogic.xml like below and it works.

```
 <wls:session-descriptor> 
        <wls:url-rewriting-enabled>false</wls:url-rewriting-enabled>
 </wls:session-descriptor>
```